# Activate on event which was off previously

Tags: jquery

I want to activate on scroll event which was previously off. Following is my code.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#dv").append('scrolled<br>');
});
$("#stop").on("click",function(){
    $(window).off("scroll");
    $("#dv").append('scroll stopped<br>');
});
$("#start").on("click",function(){
    $(window).on("scroll");
    $("#dv").append('scroll started<br>');
});
```

Please check jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5hVgZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the scroll function in a function

```
function scroll() {
     $("#dv").append('scrolled<br>');
}
```

and then call it.

```
$(window).scroll(scroll);
$("#stop").on("click", function () {

    $(window).off("scroll");
    $("#dv").append('scroll stopped<br>');
});
$("#start").on("click", function () {

    $(window).on("scroll", scroll);
    $("#dv").append('scroll started<br>');
});

function scroll() {
    $("#dv").append('scrolled<br>');
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5hVgZ/1/)**